# Any phrase to describe this situation?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

"No one bought from the salesman and **he was left with stocks of unsold goods.**"

I'm looking for a phrase or idiom, if there's any, to replace the words in bold.

Comment: There's [***left holding the baby***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hold%20the%20baby) and more generally [***left in the lurch***,](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/left_in_the_lurch.html) but I don't think there's anything as specific as "...with stocks of unsold goods".

Answer (score 1):

'Left holding the bag' seems to be what you're after, particularly in the context of finance. See: investopedia.com/terms/b/bag-holder.asp and en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagholder.

Comment: *Left holding the bag* is the perfect idiom to replace the OP's bolded text.